# How to upload file and pass a parameter, with Java web services?

Tags: java, file-upload

I am new to java web services. My objective is to pass a parameter with a file upload. Following is my code

```
@Path("/uploadservice")
public class JerseyFileUpload {
    String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "D:\\dest";
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("/upload")
    public Response uploadFile(
        FormDataMultiPart multiPart,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader
    ) throws IOException {
        InputStream fileInputStream = multiPart.getField("file").getValueAs(InputStream.class);
        id = multiPart.getField("id").getValueAs(int.class);
        saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);
        // ...
}
```

The file upload without a problem, but the `id` to be passed is throwing an exception like this:

```
2015-07-17T15:18:48.425+0530|Severe: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.typeIsKnown(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:110)
    at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.isReadable(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:345)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:315)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:298)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$23.getMessageBodyReader(WebApplicationImpl.java:1190)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.BodyPart.getEntityAs(BodyPart.java:305)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataBodyPart.getValueAs(FormDataBodyPart.java:308)
at com.upload.ws.JerseyFileUpload.uploadFile(JerseyFileUpload.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-07-17T15:18:48.429+0530|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[jersey-helloworld-serlvet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jersey-helloworld-serlvet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.typeIsKnown(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:110)
at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.isReadable(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:345)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:315)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:298)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$23.getMessageBodyReader(WebApplicationImpl.java:1190)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.BodyPart.getEntityAs(BodyPart.java:305)
at com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataBodyPart.getValueAs(FormDataBodyPart.java:308)
at com.upload.ws.JerseyFileUpload.uploadFile(JerseyFileUpload.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And my HTML form has something like this

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/FileUpload/rest/uploadservice/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="input1-css" size="50" />
    ID:<input type="number" name="id"/>

    <button type="Submit" value="Submit" />Upload</button>
</form>
```

Please tell me if I have gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@Path("/upload")` to `@Path("upload")` on method `public Response uploadFile` and see the results

Comment: Thanks but it did not work for me. . my web service is deployed on a Glass fish server and my HTML form is independent of the entire web service project. . so i had to use the entire url :  http://localhost:8080/FileUpload/rest/uploadservice/upload

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. i just modified as follows and got the output

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/upload")
public Response uploadFile(
    FormDataMultiPart multiPart,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader
    ) throws IOException {
    InputStream fileInputStream = multiPart.getField("file").getValueAs(InputStream.class);
    FormDataBodyPart b=multipart.getField("id");
    int id=Integer.parseInt(b.getValue());
    System.out.println(id);
    // ...
}
```